# How do I get an event when any option is selected for a Material UI Autocomplete React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have an autocomplete.   I need to intercept when an option is selected.  The onChange event I have bound works only when the selection, is different than the last one.  I just want to know whenever one is selected, period.   I can think of a few strategies for this, none of which seem to be provisioned by the Autocomplete API.

1. Just catch an event whenever something is selected.  This doesn't exist that I know of.
2. Always set the "current selected" option to null so everything is a change.  This doesn't exist that I know of.
3. Maybe some custom options rendering that encompasses all of the interaction logic that I am trying to avoid by using the Material UI control...is this the only way?

```
    <Autocomplete
        className={classes.textfield}
        id={entityId}
        freeSolo
        open={showSuggestions}
        onClose={handlePopoverClose}
        onChange={handleOptionSelected}
        options={options} 
        filterOptions={(options, state) => options}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField inputRef={textfieldRef} {...params} id={entityId} margin="normal" 
               onKeyPress={handleKeyPress} onInput={handleInputChanged} value={controlText}/>
        )}
      />
```

Comment: Hey, did my issue solve your question?

Answer (score 2):

According to the material ui [documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/#props), you can actually filter out the type of onChange event by accessing the second optional parameter (`reason`).

This is how you can check when any of the options are selected:

```
const handleOptionSelected = (event,value, reason) => {
  if (reason === 'select-option') {
    // do the rest
  };
};
```